# problem connecting Irobot_create, Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running the command on terminal

```
lsusb
```

it shows the serial to USB connectors connection as Sun Corp. (Suntac?):

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
**Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05db:0012 Sun Corp. (Suntac?)**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b230 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated HP HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp.
```

running the command as bellow: I got to know it is connected at ttyACM0

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

But when running command on terminal

```
rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py
```

the message appeared as"

```
could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66729/problem-connecting-irobot_create,-permission-denied:-%27/dev/ttyacm0%27?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got the solution.
just run the command to get permission.

```
sudo chmod 0777 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I found this solution but there is still a problem I have to run this command every time I start run the brown driver..
the same is with the terminal command to change the port setting from ttyS0 to ttyACM0.

```
rosparam set /brown/irobot_create_2_1/port /dev/ttyACM0
```

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1